# How to stop observing the observer when network Disconnected

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-viewmodel

I have a case like when there is network disconnection and coming back i init the viewModel which holds the observer , in this case my observer is called twice, I am suspecting that on initiating the view model again makes the observer init again, hence i am trying to clear the observer when network disconnected, say i have few observer as below

```
 private val firstObserver: MutableSharedFlow<Boolean> = MutableSharedFlow()
val firstObserverFlow: Flow<Boolean> = firstObserver

private val secondObserver: MutableSharedFlow<Boolean> = MutableSharedFlow()
val secondObserverFlow: Flow<Boolean> = secondObserver

private val thirdObserver: MutableSharedFlow<Boolean> = MutableSharedFlow()
val thirdObserverFlow: Flow<Boolean> = thirdObserver
```

In Activity i have observer as, below

```
private fun subscribeOnFirstObserverData() {
         with(viewModel) {
            firstObserverFlow.observe {
// block of code
       }
```

Now i need to stop observing all observable this on n/w disconnected , so when reconnected back there will be only one observer for each flow, which avoids multiple time of calling the block of code inside observer

Comment: You should try to check invocations of subscribeOnFirstObserverData. It should be called only once, when your screen is initialized. If this method is called when network connectivity changes, you have some error in your code logic. In general, subscribing once is enough and there's should be any necessity to handle network changes.